# Passing attribute to parent class via child in decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-3.8, six

I have this class hierarchy

```
class ParentMeta(type):
    def __new__(v1, name, b, x):
        # some code
        return super(ParentMeta, v1).__new__(v1, name, b, x)
```

and then

```
class ServiceMeta(ParentMeta, AnotherServiceMeta):
    pass
```

The `ServiceMeta` is normally used as a decorator in `add_metaclass` i.e.,

```
@add_metaclass(ServiceMeta)
class MyService(object):
    """ Code
```

The question i want to ask that how can i pass name attribute here? The `name` attribute is part of `ParentMeta`.

EDIT:

Link to `add_metaclass` documentation: https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.add_metaclass

By **default**, the `ServiceMeta` is picking up `MyService` as name for the class. I want to modify this behavior. For that reason i want to pass `name` value in decorator.

Comment: "The ServiceMeta is normally used as a decorator in add_metaclass i.e.," huh? what is `add_metaclass`??

Comment: And why would you need to pass the `name` attribute? It really is not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga see updated question

Comment: "By default, the ServiceMeta is picking up MyService as name for the class. I want to modify this behavior. For that reason i want to pass name value in decorator." There's no way to do that really if you are using a class definition statement, you'd have to use your metaclass directly to instantiate your class. So this question really has nothing to do with decorators

Comment: Also, do you *really* need to be using `six`?

Comment: ^ its an existing code base and there isn't much choice to get rid of `six`. I think my only other option is to perhaps modify `ServiceMeta` to accept `name` attribute and then pass to `ParentMeta` via `super`?

Comment: That doesn't sound related at all to what you are talking about. Again, if you *ever* want to pass that parameter to the metaclass, you have to use it directly, i.e `MyClass = MyMeta("SomeOtherName", (), {})` now `MyClass` will be a class object with a `__name__` attribute of `SomeOtherName`, which is what I thought you were trying to do

Comment: Note, `ServiveMeta` **already accepts `name`**. It really isn't clear, again, what you are asking, what is *the actual result* you are trying to achieve

Comment: how `ServiceMeta` already accepts `name`?

Comment: Because, *all metaclasses do*. I mean, you could try to write a metaclass that doesn't accept that parameter, but it wouldn't be very useful as a metaclass (unless maybe it is being used directly, `SomeClass = MyMeta()` where it is internally passing some `name` and the other arguments to `type`